# super() in python showing argument error

Tags: python, nlp, super

I have been trying paraphrase detection with a Python code. I get an error in a particular area of `super()` function. Could anyone help me with it?

The code is:

```
class MsrpCorpusPreprocessor(Preprocessor):
    def __init__(self, embed_file):
        super(MsrpCorpusPreprocessor, self).__init__(
            embed_file=embed_file,
            max_document_length=48,
            unknown="*UNKNOWN*",
            pad="*PAD*",
```

The error that i get is:

> super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj

Could anyone help?

Comment: Use `MsrpCorpusPreprocessor.__init__(self, ...)` instead.

Comment: Thankyou that error is gone,but i get a new one: def transform(self, X_raw):
        transform_each = super(MsrpCorpusPreprocessor, self)._transform_each
        X = []
        for X_raw_each in X_raw:
            X.append((transform_each(X_raw_each[0]), transform_each(X_raw_each[1])))
        return np.array(X)                                                                     
  The error is:                                                                                     
   def transform(self, X_raw):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax .i am using py2

Comment: I can't spot a mistake in that unformatted code, sorry. Maybe it's the indentation?

Comment: that was due to a missing paranthesis in super()

Comment: after i fixed that and run the code i got another error::__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unknown'

Comment: could anyone help?

Comment: Well it sounds like `Preprocessor` doesn't have a constructor parameter with the name "unknown".

Comment: it is there    class Preprocessor:

    def __init__(self,
                 embed_file,
                 max_document_length,
                 unknown="*UNKNOWN*",
                 pad="*PAD*",
                 tokenizer=None):

Comment: Then maybe you tried to pass `unknown` to `MsrpCorpusPreprocessor`? I can't debug your code without seeing it, really. There's no point playing a guessing game. If you really can't figure it out, post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: if I tried to pass unknown to MsrpCorpusPreprocesor how shall it be rectified.My code is :                                                                                                              
    class MsrpCorpusPreprocessor(Preprocessor):

    def __init__(self, embed_file,unknown):
        super(MsrpCorpusPreprocessor.__init__(self,
            embed_file=embed_file,
            max_document_length=48,
            unknown="*UNKNOWN*",
            pad="*PAD*",
        ))